# Dependency failed for mount after dist-upgrade

Tags: debian, systemd, lvm, udev, mdadm

Last weekend, I ran an `apt-get dist-upgrade` on a home Debian 8.3 system, and was surprised to see that it entered emergency mode on the next boot. The server in question runs LVM on top of a mdadm RAID 6 array. On closer inspection, it seemed to be struggling to mount the logical volumes:

[image: Boot timeout]

I've fumbled around for a week trying to fix the machine, but haven't really made any progress. I found *[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371594/systemd-udev-dependency-failure-when-auto-mounting-separate-partition-during-sta)* which details an identical problem, but under different circumstances. I tried clean installing Debian, and found that if I don't let the installer download the latest versions of packages, it boots successfully the first time, then fails after a `dist-upgrade`. If I let it download them, the box restarts straight into emergency mode after the install. This is the entry in /var/log/apt/history.log for the former scenario; interestingly, it affects all of mdadm, udev and systemd:

```
Start-Date: 2016-01-30  19:48:28
Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade
Upgrade: libpam-runtime:amd64 (1.1.8-3.1, 1.1.8-3.1+deb8u1), apt:amd64 (1.0.9.8.1, 1.0.9.8.2), multiarch-support:amd64 (2.19-18+deb8u1, 2.19-18+deb8u2), perl-base:amd64 (5.20.2-3+deb8u2, 5.20.2-3+deb8u3), libpam0g:amd64 (1.1.8-3.1, 1.1.8-3.1+deb8u1), apt-utils:amd64 (1.0.9.8.1, 1.0.9.8.2), libc-bin:amd64 (2.19-18+deb8u1, 2.19-18+deb8u2), libc6:amd64 (2.19-18+deb8u1, 2.19-18+deb8u2), mdadm:amd64 (3.3.2-5, 3.3.2-5+deb8u1), libapt-inst1.5:amd64 (1.0.9.8.1, 1.0.9.8.2), udev:amd64 (215-17+deb8u2, 215-17+deb8u3), base-files:amd64 (8+deb8u2, 8+deb8u3), libpam-modules:amd64 (1.1.8-3.1, 1.1.8-3.1+deb8u1), libudev1:amd64 (215-17+deb8u2, 215-17+deb8u3), libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 (1.0.9.8.1, 1.0.9.8.2), systemd-sysv:amd64 (215-17+deb8u2, 215-17+deb8u3), systemd:amd64 (215-17+deb8u2, 215-17+deb8u3), passwd:amd64 (4.2-3, 4.2-3+deb8u1), libpam-modules-bin:amd64 (1.1.8-3.1, 1.1.8-3.1+deb8u1), login:amd64 (4.2-3, 4.2-3+deb8u1), libsystemd0:amd64 (215-17+deb8u2, 215-17+deb8u3), libpcre3:amd64 (8.35-3.3, 8.35-3.3+deb8u2), locales:amd64 (2.19-18+deb8u1, 2.19-18+deb8u2), rsyslog:amd64 (8.4.2-1+deb8u1, 8.4.2-1+deb8u2)
End-Date: 2016-01-30  19:48:43
```

I'm really at a loss with this one. Can anyone offer any advice? As it's a clean install, I'm happy to experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. The debian maintainers added a patch to mdadm which causes the raid assembly to start before the devices are up. I have not yet completely found out why as it's supposed to fix broken RAIDs as root file system.

But you can fix it for now by downgrading the mdadm package. Get the older version from here: http://snapshot.debian.org/package/mdadm/3.3.2-5/

Probably `mdadm_3.3.2-5_amd64.deb` for you. Install it with `dpkg -i mdadm_3.3.2-5_amd64.deb`and then set it on hold until the patch is fixed. If you are using apt-get/apt use `sudo apt-mark hold mdadm` for aptitude its `aptitude hold mdadm`.

If you generally don't want your box to go into emergency mode (especially for mounts) put a nofail as option into the fstab. Also a good option is x-systemd.device-timeout so it doesn't wait 1:30min for a local device.
An example fstab entry for the raid could look like this:

`/dev/md0  /media/md0   ext4  defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=20  0  2`

The bug is being tracked in [#813335](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=813335) and it also affects 3.3.4-1.1 from testing/unstable

Comment: Is there a bug report open about this?

Comment: Thanks @lhw. I'll try your suggestions after work and report back. If one's open, a bug report would be good to have - both to add that I ran into it, and to determine when it's safe to upgrade.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I ran into the issue yesterday and did not report the bug yet. I'll do it after work so that I can include logs and systemd unit states etc.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton Are you using a raid card? Like LSI or HighPoint?

Comment: @lhw Software RAID only, but I'm using a [Supermicro X10SL7-F](http://www.supermicro.co.uk/products/motherboard/Xeon/C220/X10SL7-F.cfm), which has a LSI 2308 behind the 8 SATA ports - I don't know whether that's relevant? Two follow-up questions: 1) do you think it's better to downgrade to mdadm 3.3.2-5 rather than upgrade to 3.3.4-1.1? and 2) `/home` is also affected by the issue - presumably if I used `nofail`, I'd have login problems because my home directory wouldn't be mounted?

Comment: Upgrading to 3.3.4 would probably also work as is it does not include the line which causes the bug. And with `/home` being on the raid it depends on what you want the result to be. If it fails to mount with `nofail` you will still be able to login remotely unless you only allow ssh key login. Just your stuff won't be in your `/home`. Might be better than being completely locked out from remote logins.

Comment: @lhw Thanks - will try with 3.3.4. Public key login only and remote access isn't essential, so I'll let it go into emergency mode.

Comment: @lhw Reporting it is a good idea. But check if it has already been reported first.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it did exist for the also affected version from testing. Added the bug tracking number to the post.

Comment: Worked a treat with mdadm/3.3.4-1 - thank you again @lhw!

Comment: Was hit by this bug with the recent `Debian Jessie 8.7` and `mdadm 3.3.2-5+deb8u2` as well. Installing from `testing` `mdadm 3.4-4` solved issue for us.